# sas hadoop error - picklist

Tags: hadoop, sas

I am executing SAS program. I have declared CLASSPATH and other variables properly. However when I am defining libname to access Hadoop I am getting error. Please find attached snapshot of sas log.

```
ERROR: The Java picklist file was not found.

1          libname testdata spde './' hdfshost=default;

ERROR: tkhdjn1 constructNewObjectOfClass: failed.
ERROR: tkhdjn2 JnlFromException: Missing exception.
ERROR: Can't construct instance of class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.
ERROR: Probable classpath problem.
ERROR: Could not connect to HDFS.
ERROR: Libref TESTDATA is not assigned.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```

Can someone please look into issue and exactly let me know what is problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're not providing the correct path in your libname statement.  According to the documentation:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/engspdehdfsug/67403/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1s4fhx0fko8zkn1fiinudodmmai.htm

You should have a fully qualified path and `'./'` is not fully qualified.

If I was you, I'd focus on double checking all the requirements specified in the linked documentation.